# How to make FIO replay a trace with multiple threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, io, workbench

I run fio in this way:

fio --name=replay --filename=/dev/vdb --replay_no_stall=1 --ioengine=psync --numjobs=1 --iodepth=1 --direct=1 --invalidate=1 --verify=0 --verify_fatal=0 --group_reporting --read_iolog=wlog_k4

In wlog_k4 I sequentially write the file, now I want to use 4 threads(which means numjobs=4) and each thread run 1/4 of these write ops(without collision), there is no need to care about of the sequence between the threads, I just want to split these write ops to 4 threads, how can I achieve it?

Comment: numjobs=int
Number of clones (processes/threads performing the same workload) of this job. 
but now I want to cut the trace into four parts and each job run it's own part, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298513/how-to-make-fio-replay-a-trace-with-multiple-thread and will have the same answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41083608/7836056 ).